# How to determine if a small sample "B" could have been randomly drawn from a population "A"?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, descriptive-statistics, sample, small-sample, frequency

Given a frequency table A of outcomes for a population and a frequence table B of a small sample, could one determine if The sample B could have been randomly drawn from population A?

Comment: I believe this is exactly what the chi-square goodness of fit test does. The expected counts are those derived from the population frequency table. The null hypothesis is that the sample is drawn from a population with those expected frequencies.

Comment: The chi-square goodness of fit test is appropriate when the following conditions are met:  
1, The sampling method is simple random sampling      
2, The variable under study is categorical.   
**3, The expected value of the number of sample observations in each level of the variable is at least 5.**   
In my case, the sample observations in each level of the variable **AIN¨T** at least 5.....  

I guess this test cant be used then? :(

Comment: If you think the test suits your needs but that is the one restriction that makes you cautious, use the exact multinomial goodness-of-fit test. Here's a website about it: http://www.biostathandbook.com/exactgof.html

Comment: Please include the information I previously requested you add into your deleted version of this question. You (apparently quite deliberately) omit critical details here that will lead to advice that may be quite inappropriate. Do not delete-and-repost as a way of evading question being put on hold for clarification; if you persist in that you may simply be prevented from posting at all. The issues I raised - both in relation to the uncertainty about dependence between the sample and the larger set and in respect of the ordered categories were both directly relevant to a proper answer.

Comment: Hi Noah,  

I tried running the Chi square test in R and recieved the following results:  
**Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  observed
X-squared = 110.32, df = 7, p-value < 2.2e-16


Warning message:
In chisq.test(x = observed, p = expected) :
  Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect**

Does it mean that chi square ain´t a good fit in my case?

Comment: Yeah that's because with small counts the chi-square test may be inaccurate. Use the exact multinomial goodness-of-fit test described in the article I posted. It includes R code to run the test.

Comment: Hi again Noah, 

When running the R code for the exact multinomial gof test, I recieved the following:

**P value  (LLR)  =  0.01879
P value (Prob)  =  0.004391
P value (Chisq) =  0.001743** 

How could one interpret these results?

Comment: Would an alternative solution be to group together some categories that have a small expected value? By doing so I could decrease the degrees of freedom and thus recieve a **Chi square value of 0,99949606** and a **p value of 0,985631418**. Which of these approaches seems to make most sense?

Comment: @Noah is the exact multinomial goodness of fit test applicable if the data ain´t normally distributed?

Comment: Categorical variables can't be normally distributed, so yes. Can you please post the data? Just the frequency table for the population and the frequency table for the sample.

Answer (score 2):

Not easily. Not using any specific statistical analysis or test.

You can use a test of whether the sample is the same as the population. If you reject then you conclude that the sample is not. If you fail to reject then you do not have a clear statistical answer.

Deciding that the sample is from the population might require extensive analysis and, finally, careful scientific judgement.

Answer (score 1):

If the population random variable $X$ is categorically distributed, and each of the categories represented in the sample is a possible outcome of $X$, then the sample is necessarily a possible random sample of $X$. You don't need the counts in the frequency table to determine this.

Comment: That doesn't seem right. Couldn't you have preferential sampling, oversampling of certain categories, or sampling to fill a quota? All of those might yield a sample with all possible outcomes of X while not being random (i.e., a simple random sample, which I assume is the context of the question).

Comment: @Noah Sure you could. But the question was whether "the sample B **could have been** randomly drawn from population A" (my emphasis). An affirmative answer doesn't preclude other possibilities.